# Props is not defined using render props

Tags: reactjs

I want to build an app that uses `render.props`. I created the component where all my logic is stored:

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function Test(){
    let [click, setClick] = useState(0);
    function funClick(){
    setClick(click++)
  }
  return(
    <div>
    {props.render(click, setClick)}
    </div>
  )
}
export default Test;
```

The issue is that i've got an error `Line 10:  'props' is not defined  no-undef`. What means this error and how to solve it?

Comment: You need to define your method signature as `function Test(props)`.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html

Answer (score 2):

You need `props` as an argument for your component.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function Test(props) {
    let [click, setClick] = useState(0);
    function funClick(){
    setClick(click++)
  }
  return(
    <div>
    {props.render(click, setClick)}
    </div>
  )
}
export default Test;
```